# How to make height of jquery ui autocomplete and button the same?

Tags: jquery-ui

I use default jquery's ui autocomplete and button and their height is different:

[image: example]

Comment: Use CSS. Target the `input[type=text]` element and set the `height` property.

Comment: Surely you can specify the heights of these elements in your CSS?  What does your CSS and markup currently look like?  We can't tell from an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the button padding with:

#### CSS

```
input.ui-button {
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

work for me - see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn8J9/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var availableTags = ['Demo'];
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});

$('input:submit').button();
```

(obviously needs jQuery and jQueryUI libraries as well).